# Is it possible to have an item that is in one scene moved above another scene in Qt

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I am currently learning Qt and I want to have 2 views with 2 seperate scenes.  The second view is drawn above first one and only takes a corner of the first view.  Is it possible for a custom graphicsitem using the move mouse to be above this second view, while still having it be in the first view.  The item would actually be larger than the second view as well and it currently moves behind the second view.

Comment: You should post a diagram of what you mean, I currently don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Items belong to one scene only, you'd have to clone the item manually.